# Applying multiple filters and inputs with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two videos: `a.mp4` and `b.mp4`. I want to scale `a.mp4`, trim first 10 seconds and last 10 seconds of `b.mp4` then add subtitle to `b.mp4` then merge two videos (a.mp4 after scaling and b.mp4 after trimming/hardsub) into one. This is my script:

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -i b.mp4 -filter_complex
    '[0:v]scale=1280:720[in1];[1:v]trim=0:10,trim=110:120,ass=subtitle.ass[in2]; 
     [in1][in2] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [out]' 
    -map [out] -c:v libx264  output.mp4
```

(120 is the length in seconds of b.mp4)

but it gave me an error:

> ```
> Media type mismatch between the 'Parsed_ass_2' filter output pad 0
> (video) and the 'Parsed_concat_3' filter input pad 1 (audio)
> [AVFilterGraph @ 0x406c3c0] Cannot create the link ass:0 -> concat:1
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -i b.mp4
   -filter_complex '[0:v]scale=1280:720,setsar=1[in1];
                    [1:v]ass=subtitle.ass,trim=10:110,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,setsar=1[in2];
                    [1:a]atrim=10:110,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[1a];
                    [in1][0:a][in2][1a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]'
   -map [v] -map [a] -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

Since you are concatting audio as well, the filter expects an audio stream paired with each video stream.

Comment: Thank for your help. I tried but got this error `Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 1280x720, SAR 0:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1280x720, SAR 4757:4800) . Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_8` Do you know what's the problem?

Comment: See edited cmd.

Comment: Command runs without any error but the output video is similar to a.mp4 (but in 1280:720 resolution). It looks like `concat` is not working.

Comment: I tried this command and it works great. `ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -i b.mp4
   -filter_complex '[0:v]scale=1280:720,setsar=1[in1];
                    [1:v]ass=subtitle.ass,trim=10:110,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,setsar=1[in2];
                    [1:a]atrim=10:110,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[1a];
                    [in1][0:a][in2][1a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]'
   -map [v] -map [a] -c:v libx264 output.mp4`

Comment: Oh yeah, trim takes the time range to be **kept**. I did not bother to examine that.